# Why did my ancient question suddenly got attention?

Tags: support, specific-question

Almost exactly 4 years ago (07.18.15) I asked this average-awful question: [Naked singularity: how would it behave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194661/naked-singularity-how-would-it-behave/492387#492387). At that time I got a mediocore answer the same day that I accepted a bit later, got some views, then the question was forgotten - common boring story of most SE questions.

Fast forward exactly 4 years later (07.18.19), my completely buried post suddenly got a huge attention. In the following few days it got two great answers, two ups, comments on answers, etc., and while I'm glad this happened, I don't really understand it. The thing that makes the most sense is that some algorithm looking for old questions found it and promoted somewhere - but why even would this happen? I see no reason. My post had no activity for 4 years, was barely upvoted, and had an accepted answer, it was a completely average and forgettable one.

Was my question bumped somewhere, or is this a pure coincidence? If it was, what is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[One of those answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/402602/127931) was actually from last year (answered Apr 28 '18 at 9:43).  As you can see from the [edit history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/402602/revisions), Yukterez edited his answer on July 17th and 18th (several times).

This would have bumped the question to the top of the main page due to new activity, which generally draws attention to a question.  In this case, it led to a third answer, and thus even more attention.

So basically, it was nothing crazy.  Just regular site activity which caused the question to be bumped, leading to the attention.

Comment: oh, right. Just coincidence then.